# Error in plotting time series data with plotly, truth value is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to use plotly express to chart time series data.

I am receiving this error.There isn't any boolean values in my code so I don't understand why it isn't able to crunch this code.

ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I've looked at the data type of the dataframe and transposed and tried editing the time axis data. Dtype is dtype('0').

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly_express as px

df = pd.read_excel('FreewayFDSData.xlsx', 'Volume')
df = df.set_index("Row Labels")
detector =df.columns
time = df.index

px.scatter(df, x=detector,y=time)
```

[image]

End result is unfortunately the error code.

https://www.plotly.express/ <-- this is plotly express tutorial i am following.

```
df.head().to_dict()

{'3674S_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 88.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 116.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 84.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 68.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 76.0},
 '3674S_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 88.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 116.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 76.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 68.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 76.0},
 '3674M_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 84.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 108.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 68.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 68.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 72.0},
 '3674M_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 92.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 108.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 68.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 68.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 72.0},
 '3674EL_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 96.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 112.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 64.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 64.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 88.0},
 '3674EL_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 108.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 124.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 68.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 80.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 100.0},
 '14549IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 380.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 412.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 380.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 328.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 320.0},
 '14549IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 376.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 408.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 376.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 328.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 328.0},
 '14548IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 464.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 508.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 448.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 408.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 376.0},
 '14548IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 464.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 508.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 444.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 404.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 376.0},
 '14547IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 501.33333333333337,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 528.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 501.33333333333337,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 432.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 437.33333333333337},
 '14547IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 460.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 520.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 440.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 380.0},
 '14546IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 468.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 536.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 440.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 380.0},
 '14546IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 464.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 532.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 436.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 376.0},
 '14545IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 464.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 524.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 448.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 400.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 384.0},
 '14545IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 468.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 516.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 444.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 380.0},
 '14544IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 440.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 516.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 440.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 380.0},
 '14544IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 444.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 512.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 444.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 392.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 364.0},
 '14543IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 456.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 524.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 440.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 364.0},
 '14543IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 452.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 528.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 444.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 400.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 368.0},
 '14542IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 444.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 516.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 432.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 368.0},
 '14542IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 444.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 528.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 428.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 396.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 356.0},
 '14540IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 384.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 412.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 352.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 340.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 300.0},
 '14540IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 384.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 408.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 348.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 332.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 304.0},
 '14537IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 420.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 420.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 340.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 330.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 300.0},
 '14537IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 530.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 565.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 455.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 445.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 420.0},
 '14536IB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 296.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 260.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 300.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 212.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 260.0},
 '14536IB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 304.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 256.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 290.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 208.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 256.0},
 '14405WB_P1': {'00:00 - 00:15': 504.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 520.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 456.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 428.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 376.0},
 '14405WB_P0': {'00:00 - 00:15': 504.0,
  '00:15 - 00:30': 524.0,
  '00:30 - 00:45': 448.0,
  '00:45 - 01:00': 420.0,
  '01:00 - 01:15': 376.0}}
```

Comment: Do you mind to share `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: df.head().to_dict()

Comment: This usually happens when you have multiple copies of the same instance. You need to check the df.columns list to see if a column has been added twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use plotly_express for your problem as `x` and `y` should be strings. Check the output of px.scatter?

```
px.scatter?
data_frame: A 'tidy' `pandas.DataFrame`
x: (string, name of column in `data_frame`) Values from this column are used to position marks along the x axis in cartesian coordinates.
y: (string, name of column in `data_frame`) Values from this column are used to position marks along the y axis in cartesian coordinates.
```

Given that installing plotly_express you get plotly too you can just use

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# here I'm using your df.head().to_dict() as dct
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
traces = [go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                     y=df[col],
                     name=col)
          for col in df.columns]


py.iplot(traces)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Plotly Express, and this is indeed the case right now. We're looking at possibly adding the ability to pass in df.index or df.my_column ... discussion in https://github.com/plotly/plotly_express/issues/37

Comment: In the meantime I've added stricter validation and better error messages to avoid this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

On my phone right now, but wanted to assist asap so  I'll handle proper formatting later.

The data type sure seems to be the problem here. You're setting `time = df.index` and later you're assigning time to y in `px.scatter(df, x=detector,y=time)`. And the first value of `df.index` is `36745_P1`. So there's your problen as far as I can tell right now. What values for x and y do you really want to plot?

Comment: I want to plot all of them if possible, so all the detectors versus all time

Comment: To use Plotly Express you would have to reshape your data to have three columns: time, detector, value. For the shape of data you have, you will likely want to use `cufflinks` to do `df.iplot(...)`.